# angular js add css when a variable becomes true

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I am new to angular js. I am trying to change the border of the fields to red when empty form is submitted. 
I have written controller where it processes the input when valid form is submitted and just makes a field(invalidFormSubmitted) to true when invalid form is submitted.

I tried below css but it is not working

```
 input.invalidFormSubmitted{
  border-bottom: 0.125rem solid #e42105;
  }
```

I also tried with  ng-submitted, but no luck.

How do i make the field border red when this variable is set to true?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: .ng-invalid input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this.

```js
var app = angular.module("app",[]);

app.controller("MyCtrl" , function($scope){
  
 
  
  });
```

```css
.invalidFormSubmitted{
  border-bottom: 0.125rem solid #e42105;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
   <form name="form">
         <input name="name" ng-model="name" ng-required="true" ng-class="{'invalidFormSubmitted': form.name.$invalid && check}"> 
      <button type="button" name="button" ng-click="check = true">ENVIAR</button>
     </form>
 
 
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

you're looking for `ng-class`

```js
angular.module('app',[]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<style>
input.invalidFormSubmitted{
 border:1px solid red;
}
</style> 
<div ng-app="app">
<form name="myForm">
  <input type="text" required ng-model="foo" name="sample" ng-class="{'invalidFormSubmitted':myForm.sample.$invalid}" />
</form>
</div>
```

As you can see the class is applied as long there is no value in the input here